# On the Fly JQuery Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I am working with a Responsive Design website, more specifically a page that incorporates several Divs. When you re-size the webpage the width of the divs change as they are set as percentages. As the height has to stay constant, unless the div will disappear, I have to set break-points to change the height. If I don't change the height, it stays constant and adds "margin" between divs below. Essentially, my logic is: when the window is re-sized and the width is less than 810px, then remove all CSS styling, and add margin top, items 2 through infinity. As this is hard to explain through writing, I have added the following code at the end.

When I re-size the browser window, and the content div is less than 810px, styling is not removed. Looking at my code, what could be the culprit?

The function is at lines 27-50: https://github.com/jdmagic21/coded_container/blob/master/work.js

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing it with Javascript, you should consider using CSS Media Queries to change the styles depending on the width of the browser.

[Here's a tutorial - one of the top hits on Google for "How to use CSS Media Queries"](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html)

[Here's a table of browser compatibility for Media Queries.  As long as you don't care too much about IE8 or previous, you're ok!](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with CSS Media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 810px) {
     /* reset the styles of the divs here */
}
```